# When using Cloo in C#, ComputePlatform.Platforms.Count is zero, even though I have a graphics card installed (obviously)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, count, zero, cloo

I need to access my graphics card using Cloo in C#. When I try to access it through ComputePlatform.Platforms, this list is empty.
My drivers are up to date, I have tried doing this is Visual Studio 2013 and 2015, but no results.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I needed to download and install the [CUDA Drivers](https://developer.nvidia.com/cuda-downloads), this fixed the problem.